# Get list of used configuration files from Nose

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

From the code that runs the tests using nose, how do I retrieve a list of config files that have been passed on the command line (without parsing the args myself since nose should expose these values somewhere) as in,

```
nosetests -c default.ini -c staging.ini
```

which would then result in,

```
[default.ini, staging.ini]
```

I can't seem to find these values on the nose.config object.

Comment: Have you tried `nose.config.user_config_files()` or `nose.config.all_config_files()` ?

Comment: I have and they both turn up empty.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your problem is that you're naming your configuration files differently than what the default nose configuration files should be named.

From nose.config

```
config_files = [
    # Linux users will prefer this
    "~/.noserc",
    # Windows users will prefer this
    "~/nose.cfg"
    ]

def user_config_files():
    """Return path to any existing user config files
    """
    return filter(os.path.exists,
                  map(os.path.expanduser, config_files))


def all_config_files():
    """Return path to any existing user config files, plus any setup.cfg
    in the current working directory.
    """
    user = user_config_files()
    if os.path.exists('setup.cfg'):
        return user + ['setup.cfg']
    return user
```

The short of this is, that nose is looking for default configuration files named ~/.noserc or ~/nose.cfg. If they're not named like this nose will not pick them up and you will have to **manually** specify the name of the configuration files, like you are doing on the command line

Now say for instance that you have some object **config** which is an *instance* of **nose.config.Config** then the best way to get your config file names would be to say

```
>>> from nose.config import Config
>>> c = Config()
>>> c.configure(argv=["nosetests", "-c", "foo.txt"])
>>> c.options.files
['foo.txt']
```